# How to make the zsh "correct" functionality remember my spell-correction decisions

Tags: zsh, alias, spell-checking, autocorrection

I have enabled correction (I wouldn't call it *autocorrection* specifically because of this issue) in zsh by enabling `setopt correct` in my `.zshrc`.

Now, when I type `dtae` in a terminal, I get:

```
dtae        
zsh: correct 'dtae' to 'date' [nyae]? y
Tue Mar 31 11:39:31 CEST 2015
```

At this point I would like zsh to remember my decision. So the next time I type `dtae` it should automatically correct to `date` [1]. However, this does not happen, and zsh is again asking me what to do:

```
dtae
zsh: correct 'dtae' to 'date' [nyae]?
```

[1] Unless, of course, if at that time there exists an actual `dtae` command or alias.

**Update:**

I have managed to modify the zsh source code (file `utils.c`, function `spckword`) to create a custom file containing the aliases automatically created with the invocation of zsh's "correct" functionality:

original:

```
if (x == 'y' || x == ' ' || x == '\t') 
{
    *s = dupstring(best);
    if (hist)
    hwrep(best);
}
```

modified:

```
if (x == 'y' || x == ' ' || x == '\t')
{
    char *aliaspath = getenv("HOME");
    strcat(aliaspath, "/.zsh_correct_aliases");
    FILE *out = fopen(aliaspath, "ab+");
    fprintf(out, "alias %s=\'", *s);
    *s = dupstring(best);
    fprintf(out, "%s\'\n", *s);
    fclose(out);
    if (hist)
    hwrep(best);
}
```

Upon executing `dtae`, the following line is added to the file `~/.zsh_correct_aliases`:

```
alias dtae='date'
```

However, I don't know how to source the newly modified `~/.zsh_correct_aliases` file in-place.

Comment: Do you want it remembered only for the shell process lifetime, or that information stored in files. Should that remembered correction be immediately available to all currently running shell instances? Do you want the remembered correction removed when `dtae` spawns into existence or just disabled temporarily?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas 1) Stored in a single file would be best. 2) It would be a plus, but not strictly necessary. 3) Removed until `dtae` exists, then reinstated if/when `dtae` is not defined anymore.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas please see my update, am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: It would probably make more sense to call a dedicated zsh hook function there (like a `command_not_found_handler` but at parsing time instead of runtime), and then implement the logic in zsh code.

Comment: See the `precmd` hook to run commands before each prompt (like sourcing your zsh aliases)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I understand what you mean with the handler but since I have absolutely no experience with C programming I'm afraid this is out of my reach. Will look into `precmd`.

Comment: You could suggest it to the zsh developers (zsh-workers mailing list). They're usually very reactive.

Comment: I do not think this is considered good practice... I feel it is much more efficient to learn how to type correctly.

Comment: I'm just curious, for this specific use at least, why not just have the code add the aliases to the end of .zshrc, or somehow do that same but by cating .zsh_correct_aliases into .zshrc.  Obscursing that with some hashing, obscurity/variables, or better, as needed for security

Comment: what if you changed autocorrect so that `dtae` becomes `alias dtae=date; date`?

Answer (score 3):

You could base your code on the built-in alias defined [here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/5f6a52c06ca956cf61eacd7f45f270899337d45e/Src/builtin.c#L4257)

```
HashTable ht = aliastab;
ht->addnode(ht, ztrdup(wrong_value),
            createaliasnode(ztrdup(right_value), 0));
```

(not tested)

And add `source ~/.zsh_correct_aliases` to you .zshrc

---

**EDIT**: tested with source:

```
char *aliaspath = getenv("HOME");
strcat(aliaspath, "/.zsh_correct_aliases");

FILE *out = fopen(aliaspath, "ab+");
fprintf(out, "alias %s=\'", *s);

HashTable ht = aliastab;
ht->addnode(ht, ztrdup(*s),
    createaliasnode(ztrdup(best), 0));

*s = dupstring(best);
fprintf(out, "%s\'\n", *s);
fclose(out);
if (hist)
    hwrep(best);
```

It gives:

```
$ setopt correct 
$ dtea    
zsh: correct 'dtea' to 'date' [nyae]? y
lun. janv.  8 01:03:55 CET 2018  
$ alias  
dtea=date
$ dtea    
lun. janv.  8 01:07:42 CET 2018
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a precmd function that sources ~/.zsh_correct_aliases.