# Automatically correct simple spelling mistakes in zsh?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, autocorrection

How do I tell zsh to correct simple spelling mistakes automatically?

For example:
I want `lsbkl` to automatically be corrected to `lsblk`, after hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, without showing `zsh: correct 'lsbkl' to 'lsblk' [nyae]?`.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Related: [How to make the zsh “correct” functionality remember my spell-correction decisions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193552)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will autocorrect the word to the left of the cursor whenever you press <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```bsh
autocorrect() {
  zle .spell-word
  zle .$WIDGET
}
zle -N accept-line autocorrect
zle -N magic-space autocorrect
bindkey ' ' magic-space
```

Comment: I don't want to define the corrections by hand though.

Comment: @weisbrja I updated my answer with a solution that doesn't require manually defining corrections. Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is literally perfect!